# Wordpress on HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, authentication, https

I've recently moved my website over to `https://` and have re-installed WordPress to this new platform. 
The SSL certificates are installed correctly in the appropriate directories. The certificate installation has been completed by my web hosting supplier. The wordpress installation is in a sub directory of the root https://www.mysite.co.uk/blog/. So far so good.

The normal website pages (which are external to WordPress) all function as required and normally merge posts from the blog, which appear in the page footer and in sidebars. These are currently suspended pending resolution of the WordPress issue.

The issue that I'm experiencing is simply that I cannot log in to WordPress. The admin log in panel at https://www.mysite.co.uk/blog/wp-login.php is displayed, however, when entering the correct username and password combination the `wp-login.php` simply goes through a loop but doesn't allow me to login irrespective of password and username combination.

Here's what I've tried:

I've changed the appropriate lines in `wp-config.php` to force an SSL login:

After `WP_DEBUG` in `wp-config.php` I added the following lines:

```
define( 'FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true );
define( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true );
```

But with no result. Does anyone know what the potential issue might be?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code in wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','https://www.mysite.co.uk/blog/');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://www.mysite.co.uk/blog/');
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this answer, unfortunately it didn't work. It did  throw a few certificate errors though. The basic problem is that the installation of Wordpress is handled by my webhost and this automatically places wordpress in a subdirectory but uses the http:// prefix and not https://. This, I believe is where the issue lies. I assume that wp-config.php is not using https:// to communicate with the database?